# how to create a contact form in Joomla 2.5 without using an extension

Tags: forms, joomla2.5, contactus

I'm working towards keeping site light.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this works: <http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/joomla25/joomla25-contact-us-page.htm>

Comment: Yes the link gave me good start...just need to tweak it some with site owner...

Comment: Unfortunately the form fields are not responsive - they run off the side in iPhone. <http://www.pawsingoodcare.com/contact-us>.  Where and how would I edit the css in this form created in Joomla Contact Manager? Should I start a new Question?

Comment: I'm finding it's using overrrides. Some instructions: <http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core>, <http://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/overrides/>, and <https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/joomla-templates/1067-customize-your-joomla-templates-by-learning-overrides>

Comment: Ended up using custom.css (Yootheme). Site was responsive. Form was not. Using Emulator in Developer tools in Chrome Canary was helpful in finding css to modify. Settings to make form responsive:    Using these settings the Joomla contact form is responsive: #system form.submission fieldset > div > input[type='text'], #system form.submission fieldset > div > input[type='password'] { padding: 5px; width: 92%; } #system form.submission fieldset > div > textarea { width: 95%; ; }